# How to decrypt data in binary file by XOR operator using a given key at specific offset?

Tags: linux, decryption, decompress, xor, command-line

I've a binary data files which are encrypted by a simple [XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) using a given key at offset `+0x88` (which is `0x80` long), then the data (`+0x108`) is compressed by `lzo1x`.

What would be the most efficient way of decrypting such files?

Preferably by using some command-line utilities (where I can specify the input offsets) or some script (without too much coding)?

What would be the right approach?

Comment: The right approach is writing script in a language of your choice. I'd do it in Python.

Comment: As @ws suggested, you should just take your favorite language and make a tool for that... In fact, I don't see the point of this question. Am I missing something ?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: @perror The point is to have useful Q&A about simple XOR deciphering (which seems there is a lack in here) and to share the knowledge. I don't see the reason why criticise the question by people who doesn't know the answer.

Comment: @ws Now there is one.

Comment: @kenorb: If you were doing real reverse-engineering, usually when you encounter xored asm code in a binary, there will be another part of the code to decipher it... There is no need to create an external tool to do it as it should be contained in the binary you are currently looking at. But, it's just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dd` to extract the data what you need, e.g. (using bash syntax):

```
dd if=foo.dat bs=1 skip=$((0x88)) count=$((0x80)) of=xorkey.bin
dd if=foo.dat bs=1 skip=$((0x108)) of=data1.bin
```

Then convert it using simple Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def str_xor(data, key):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] ^= key[i % len(key)]
    return data

key  = bytearray(open('xorkey.bin', 'rb').read())
data = bytearray(open('data1.bin',  'rb').read())
encoded = str_xor(data, key)
open("data1.bin.xor", "wb").write(encoded)
decoded = str_xor(data, key)
open("data1.bin.xor.xor", "wb").write(decoded)
```

Then install `lzop` tool which offers compression/decompression of the LZO1X algorithms (install via: `apt-get`/`brew` `install lzop`), e.g.:

```
lzop -dc data1.bin.xor > data1.out
```

Comment: you could use powershell to get the bytes from a specific block of file and use it foreach operator to xor the bytes like this $foo=(($c=gc .\encrypted.dat -Encoding byte)[0x80..$C.Length]) |%{$_ -bxor 63}

Comment: Instead of writing your own python code, you can use `xortool-xor` from https://github.com/hellman/xortool